# TortoiseSVN proxy settings per repo, instead of global?

Tags: svn, proxy, tortoisesvn

With TortoiseSVN it is easy to enable or disable a proxy server.

This can be done with `Right Click->TortoiseSvn->Settings->Network->and click the enable/disable proxy server check box`.

Here is a screen shot showing this feature:

[image]

This feature is a global setting and will apply to all TortoiseSVN repositories that I have checked out on my computer. This causes me a head-ache because half of my repositories require a proxy, and the other half do not. The problem is that I have to manually switch back and forth the proxy settings. I would expect that this can be made automatic using a setting.

Does anyone know how to establish proxy server settings (or lack thereof) on a per-checked-out-repository basis?

While googling I discovered there are settings in files located in this folder:

```
%APPDATA%\Subversion\
```

And in particular, I thought I would be able to add per-repo proxy settings to the servers file...but I don't see where or how.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the [`%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers` file](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/confarea/#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers) or [Windows Registry](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/confarea/#svn.advanced.confarea.windows-registry.ex-1) to configure server groups and make the Subversion client use a proxy only on the servers you choose. You can also use the `http-proxy-exceptions` configuration option.